How to install light fixture / receptacle to a light switch that isnt being used?
I have no light fixture or even a spot in my living room ceiling for light but I have a working light switch that isn't connected to anything.
Is there a way I can install a light fixture/ ceiling fan from ceiling to that light switch that isn't being used?
 

Most people do not put a light switch in a wall for no reason.  We need to know the type/wires on the switch, if it has power, and why you do not use it/are you sure it does not control something.

If it's not connected to anything, how do you know it's working?

Sure, You run cable from the switch box up the wall and through the ceiling to the box that you must install in the ceiling.
The details of doing that we cannot help with until you give far more information about your home.
The switch that "doesn't do anything" probably activates an outlet in the room. Possibly just the upper or lower part of an outlet. So you can plug in a lamp and light the room when entering in the dark.
The fact that you don't have a ceiling light supports this theory, since it is a code requirement that a ceiling light or a switched outlet is necessary at the entrance of every room.
Check all the outlets. If a ceiling light is still desired, modify your question or submit another with the information about your home like, type of construction, what's over the LR ceiling, and what's on the other side of the wall with the switch box. (It looks like a manufactured home). Let us know how much work your are comfortable with doing and what your knowledge of home electrical systems is.

The outlet may be half-switched. That is to say, on a dual outlet, only the (usually) bottom or top outlet is switched and the other is always live. If none seem to be switched, the outlets may have been replaced but the metal tab separating the hots not removed.

The other thing to watch out for: if the light switch currently has a black wire on one screw and a white wire on the other screw then it is a switch loop and you must rewire things at the source (switched receptacle most likely) because that white wire is not neutral.
